# BigCommerce API 3 is not clear on listing variation product

Tags: bigcommerce

While listing a variation product in BigCommerce V3 is a big clumsy, There is a mandatory field "option_values" which is to be provided with Id, and option_id. The API 3 has not provided any option how to create the these values before listing the variation. in V2 there is an option to create and later attach option to optionset and thereafter attach optionset to product and list the product providing the option details. But nothing is clear in API 3 (V3). Can any one guide me how tackle this in API 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v3 does not have individual option sets. In v3, the options are attached to the products and once you create and attach the options (to create variants) it's impossible to add/remove individual options from or to the products using the control panel. You either remove all, or keep it as is. It's a tad bit worse than clumsy.

You'll have to use v2 to create option sets.

https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00003ojnDxSAI/how-to-add-a-product-with-option-set-by-api

https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B000048Pm4rSAC/can-you-please-explain-how-the-current-solution-of-option-sets-and-option-set-rules-is-handled-in-the-v3-api

Comment: Thanks, I got some clue. Now I can move further

Comment: Good answer @ReturnTable :) I'd add that in the future, we plan to make the control panel reflect the v3 data model to make products easier to manage between the API and control panel.

Comment: @KarenWhite that's what I was suspecting of :) I assume it's for the best (thinking from the logical side) to make the products the center of orientation instead of a planetary structure with option sets, option set rules, product rules, SKUs etc.
However many stores will have incredibly hard time adjusting the new product oriented structure instead of the planetary system. We were able to stop using option set rules for example, but even that was a large & tedious transition and took a very long time for 10k+ products.